# Zip elements of a 2 different length lists in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was wondering is there a way to zip 2 lists of different lengths by not missing any element in python?

Or create a table?

Example:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
b=[7,3,5,2]
```

Expected output: `(1,7),(2,3),(3,5),(4,2),(5),(6),(7)`

Or

```
1  7

2  3

3 5

4 2

5

6

7
```

Comment: [`itertools.izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest)

Comment: As @jonrsharpe suggests, the `itertools` module has a method for just that, however in python 3 it is just `itertools.zip_longest()`.